# Anonymous Function prints as string

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I wanted to calculate total of two variables received from textbox, let us say `txtBoxA` and `txtBoxB`. The value gets calculated in an anonymous function and is stored in a variable `total`. Please take a look at the following code to see how it is calculated:

```
var total = function () {
            var total = parseFloat(txtbox[1].value) + parseFloat(txtbox[2].value);
            if (total == NaN) return 0;
            else return total;
        };
        alert(total);
```

but unfortunately, the anonymous function itself is printed as it is as shown in the image below.
[image: Anonymous Function Printed as text]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alert(total);
```

You are just printing the function variable. If you want to execute it, you have to add `()`, so that it calls.

```
 alert(total());
```

And that is not an anonymous function. Just a function declaration and assigning to a variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Suresh :) . It works
Sorry got confused. I'll edit the question too ASAP

Comment: but bro, W3Schools said it was an anonymous function.. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp